# Select rows with the same Item name and show lowest Price

Tags: mysql

We have a two tables laid out as:

```
Products
ID | Item | Supplier
1 | Harry Potter | Warner
2 | Harry Potter | Warner
3 | Game of Thrones | HBO
4 | The Simpsons | Warner
5 | The Simpsons | Warner
```

AND

```
Prices
ID | Price
1 | 10.99
2 | 20.00
3 | 20.00
4 | 10.00
5 | 12.00
```

I'm trying to get the ID of the lowest priced Item where there are two items with the same name and supplier.

I can get the rows where there are duplicates as:

```
SELECT
Products.ID,Products.Item,Products.Supplier,Prices.price
FROM
Products
LEFT JOIN Prices ON Prices.ID = Products.ID
WHERE Products.ID IN (
SELECT ID FROM Products WHERE Supplier="Warner" GROUP BY Item HAVING count(*) > 1
)
```

How can I then modify this to show only the Products.ID of the lowest priced duplicate Item name ?

I have tried ORDER BY but this throws an error for me.

The result should be:

```
ID | Item | Supplier | Price
1 | Harry Potter | Warner | 10.99
4 | The Simpsons | Warner | 10.00
```

Thanks,

Rick

Comment: How do you know which price is related to a product ? Are you sure `Prices.ID` will always match a `Product.ID` ?

Comment: They're joined on the ID. At the moment it's simply showing the highest price.

Comment: That means that a product can have only one price... Then why don't you just add a field `price` in your `Products` table ?

Comment: That would still just give the rows with the same name value rather than showing the one with the lowest price that's a duplicated Item, or am I missing something simple !?

Answer (score 0):

first of all your implementation of tables has to improve if you have ID as a primary key in Products table your data will be as follows (YOU NEED a primary key).

```
Products
ID | Item | Supplier
1 | Harry Potter | Warner
2 | Game of Thrones | HBO

Prices
ID | Price
1 | 10.99
1 | 20.00
2 | 20
```

Now in order to select the lowest prices items use the min function

```
SELECT
Products.ID,Products.Item,Products.Supplier, MIN(Prices.price)
FROM
Products
LEFT JOIN Prices ON Prices.ID = Products.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Oracle syntax  
with Products as  
(  
select 1 id, 'Harry Potter' item,  'Warner' supplier from dual union all  
select 2 id, 'Harry Potter' item,  'Warner' supplier from dual union all  
select 3, 'Game of Thrones', 'HBO' from dual union all  
select 4, 'the simpsons', 'Warner' from dual union all  
select 5, 'the simpsons', 'Warner' from dual  
),  
Prices as  
(  
select 1 id, 10.99 price from dual union all  
select 2, 20.00 from dual union all   
select 3, 20.00 from dual union all  
select 4, 10.00 from dual union all  
select 5, 12.00 from dual)  
*/  

select distinct p.id from Products p join Prices c  
on (p.id = c.id)   
where (p.item, p.supplier, c.price) in  
(select item, supplier, min(price) from Products p join Prices c on (p.id = c.id) group by item, supplier having count(item) > 1);
```

(if several products have the same item value and price this query will show both products)

Comment: Thanks, totally get the theory. Create a table with the names and lowest prices then get the id's of the products that match that. I'm having an issue with the use of MIN() in the sub-select though. It always hangs when the query is executed however if I just mention an item by name in the sub query (WHERE item="harry potter") and remove the min() it works fine.